# Maven: org.libreoffice version 7 jar files contains only one metadata file

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, libreoffice

Today I wanted to update my maven configurations to the latest version in pom.xml. But when maven downloaded the latest version of org.libreoffice 7.5.3 I couldn't compile because the jar files doesn't contain any classes. Only the metadata is provided.
It concerns artifactIds: 'unoil', 'juh', 'ridl' and 'jurt'.

After some research I noticed that this happens for all versions 7.x.x . The latest version that compile without error is 6.4.7
Here is part of my pom.xml:

```
...
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.libreoffice</groupId>
  <artifactId>unoil</artifactId>
  <version>7.5.3</version>                                                       </dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.libreoffice</groupId>
  <artifactId>juh</artifactId>                                                          
  <version>7.5.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.libreoffice</groupId>                                             
  <artifactId>ridl</artifactId>
  <version>7.5.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>                                                                                    
  <groupId>org.libreoffice</groupId>
  <artifactId>jurt</artifactId>
  <version>7.5.3</version>
</dependency>
...
```

The information about the version came from 'http://mvnrepository.com'.

Here are the files into the jar:

```
$> jar -tfv ~/.m2/repository/org/libreoffice/unoil/7.5.3/unoil-7.5.3.jar
     0 Fri Apr 28 11:48:14 CEST 2023 META-INF/
   118 Fri Apr 28 11:48:14 CEST 2023 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
```

The content:

```
$> cat META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Solar-Version: 7.5.3.2
Class-Path:  libreoffice.jar
Created-By: 1.8.0_362 (Red Hat, Inc.)
```

Here is the trace when compiling

```
...
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/libreoffice/unoil/7.5.3/unoil-7.5.3.pom
Progress (1): 1.7 kB
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/libreoffice/juh/7.5.3/juh-7.5.3.pom
Progress (1): 1.6 kB
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/libreoffice/ridl/7.5.3/ridl-7.5.3.pom
Progress (1): 1.7 kB
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/libreoffice/jurt/7.5.3/jurt-7.5.3.pom
Progress (1): 1.6 kB
...
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/libreoffice/unoil/7.5.3/unoil-7.5.3.jar
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/libreoffice/juh/7.5.3/juh-7.5.3.jar
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/libreoffice/ridl/7.5.3/ridl-7.5.3.jar
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/libreoffice/jurt/7.5.3/jurt-7.5.3.jar
...
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /xxx/src/main/java/yyy/util/libreoffice/zzz1.java:[27,32] package com.sun.star.comp.helper does not exist
[ERROR] /xxx/src/main/java/yyy/util/libreoffice/zzz2.java:[28,32] package com.sun.star.comp.helper does not exist
[ERROR] /xxx/src/main/java/yyy/util/libreoffice/zzz1.java:[23,26] package com.sun.star.beans does not exist
[ERROR] /xxx/src/main/java/yyy/util/libreoffice/zzz2.java:[24,26] package com.sun.star.beans does not exist
[ERROR] /xxx/src/main/java/yyy/util/libreoffice/zzz3.java:[25,26] package com.sun.star.beans does not exist
[ERROR]
...
```

thank you in advance for your help

Comment: Try this one instead: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.libreoffice/libreoffice. The POM of unoil has a dependency management section which refers to it. Because it's in dependency management and not dependencies, it's not a transitive dependency to your project.